# Is there an equivalent to IServiceCollection's "TryAdd" methods for use with the IOptions<T> pattern?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, .net-core

I find the .NET Core IOptions pattern, as expressed in the syntax below, to be quite helpful.

```
services.Configure<MySettings>(configuration.GetSection("MySettings"));
```

I also find the TryAdd methods helpful for guarding against duplicating a service registration, like this:

```
services.TryAddTransient<IMyService, MyService>();
```

I'm wondering if anyone knows of any technique for accomplishing the same thing with IOptions, or if duplicate registration protection is, perhaps, built into the framework.  In other words, I'm looking for something like this:

```
services.TryConfigure<MySettings>(configuration.GetSection("MySettings"));
```

Comment: TryAdd speaks of worries about Race Conditions. Or generally a Multitasking focus for this class. This can include the function be called from Multiple Programms (like is the case with most Windows API functions - unless you got a locking mechanic in place instead. You find it in Concurrent Collections, the Channel (a modified Queue) and similar cases.

Comment: This is not true with any `TryParse` and `TryAdd` on `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>`. Especially on key-value structures it's rather an alternative to throwing exception on attempt to add duplicate key.

Comment: The point of the IServiceCollection TryAdd methods isn't to deal with concurrency issues, and the container won't throw an exception on duplicate keys. I assume the OP is trying to add a "sane default" IOptions registration as part of a framework, and wants to allow framework users to optionally replace that registration. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41743150/aspnet-core-di-tryadd-vs-add-usage) for an explanation of the pattern.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually, I had the same "issue". I resolved in this way:

```
if (!services.Any(d => d.ServiceType == typeof(IConfigureOptions<MySettings>)))
{
    services.Configure<MySettings>(configSection);
}
```

This solution was based [on Microsoft TryAdd code](https://github.com/aspnet/DependencyInjection/blob/master/src/DI.Abstractions/Extensions/ServiceCollectionDescriptorExtensions.cs#L88).

Tip: You can create an extension method for it.

Comment: Why the scare quotes? Maybe it’s not a serious issue, but I don’t think I suggested it was. I was merely curious if there was a built-in technique, or another reason not to write my own extension method (which is how I handled it, if I recall correctly).

Comment: Sorry, it was not my intention to complain or try to belittle your question with scary quotes. I'm not native English.
This is a valid question and I had the same one, that's why I found your question

I wasn't able to find a native extension

Comment: Ah okay, then disregard that! This looks correct, so I’ll accept the answer. Should the “TOptions” be “MySettings” though? I’m not at my machine to verify at the moment.

Comment: Yes, you are correct I forgot to change.

Updated


thank you :)